# Not Getting Value in Mysql parameter

Tags: mysql, select, split, substring

```
SELECT INSTR('359616044513513-2574', '-')
```

I want to assign values to variables like **dev=359616044513513** and **id=2574**

How can I do it in stored procedure of MYSQL?

Comment: Are you defining that in a procedure or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('359616044513513-2574', '-', 1), 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX('359616044513513-2574', '-', -1) INTO @dev, @id;
```